# Expanding environment variables in active-directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to set a user's profilePath like this:

```
$commonname = "Firstname lastname"
$samaccountname = "some-user-name"
$user = organizationalUnit.create("user", "CN=$commonname")
$user.invokeset("SamaccountName", $samaccountname)
$user.commitchanges()
$profilePath = "\\domain.local\profiles\%USERNAME%"
$user.invokeset("profilePath", $profilePath)
$user.commitchanges()
```

When I look at the newly set attribute however, the %USERNAME% variable does not get expanded to "some-user-name". When I type the same profile path in the windows server manager gui for active-directory and click "Apply", it does get expanded.

How can I make the %USERNAME% variable expand?

Answer (score 1):

You can access environment variables via `$env:variablename` syntax. Like so,

```
$profilePath = "\\domain.local\profiles\$env:username"
```

Comment: Sorry if that was unclear, but I need to insert (many) names different from mine.

Comment: Isn't the username the same as the samaccountname?